# Can supercharger/turbocharger increase absolute ceiling

Tags: aircraft-performance

Superchargers and turbochargers can increase the service ceiling. Then what about the absolute ceiling? Can superchargers or turbochargers increase it?

Comment: You mean absolute ceiling?

Comment: @Sanchises oh yes. Thanks

Comment: "Then what about the absolute ceiling? Can superchargers or turbochargers increase it?" -- how could they not?

Answer (score 3):

A turbocharger or supercharger increases the available power, and thus the climb rate, at all altitudes. The absolute ceiling is just where the maximum possible climb rate reaches 0 fpm, so increasing the available power at this altitude will raise the absolute ceiling to a higher altitude.

Answer (score 1):

Although forced induction can increase the absolute ceiling from an aircraft performance point of view (the definition of the term), keep in mind that there may be other restrictions on the maximum altitude for the aircraft to fly at.

Presumably an aircraft with forced induction will have pressurized magnetos, but un-pressurized magnetos won't work beyond a certain altitude.

Cabin pressurization limits -- there are structural limits on how much delta-P you can sustain.  As you go higher (while maintaining a constant cabin altitude), this pressure will increase.

There are also procedural limits to cabin pressurization -- i.e. the regs say that in the event of rapid depressurization, you have to be able to get back down to breathable levels in a certain amount of time.  This generally prevents civil aircraft from flying above 45000 ft.  The Concorde flew at 60kft, but it may have had special dispensation.  These are higher levels than a piloted piston-prop aircraft would consider, but you get the idea.

As you go higher (say at constant equivalent airspeed), your true airspeed increases.  The air also gets colder -- which reduces the speed of sound.  Consequently, the Mach number increases.  The aircraft may start to encounter compressible aerodynamic effects -- first on the propeller, but the instrumentation, and wings will be affected.

Aircraft like the Golbal Hawk are simultaneously flying on the verge of stall, buffett, and compressibility effects.

So, yes you can increase the absolute ceiling with forced induction -- but don't forget all the other things that happen with increased altitude.